# How to change background of Org-mode's source code block only from the indentation of #+BEGIN_SRC?

Tags: org-mode

In Org-mode, I wonder if the background color of the source code block can be changed only from the indentation of #+BEGIN_SRC?

Here is the current background in my Org-mode:

[image]

Is it possible to change its background to something like this?
Note that the background of the first few columns of the code environment is unchanged.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple configuration option that you can change to do this; you would need to change the org-mode code.

That said, you should be aware that the content of the code block includes the spaces at the beginning of the lines.